# R: Remove duplicates from a dataframe based on categories in a column

Tags: r

Here is my example data set:

```
      Name Course Cateory
 1: Jason     ML      PT
 2: Jason     ML      DI
 3: Jason     ML      GT
 4: Jason     ML      SY
 5: Jason     DS      SY
 6: Jason     DS      DI
 7: Nancy     ML      PT
 8: Nancy     ML      SY
 9: Nancy     DS      DI
10: Nancy     DS      GT
11: James     ML      SY
12:  John     DS      GT
```

I want to delete the duplicate rows to have unique rows across the dataframe. Deleting the duplicate rows is based on the values from the column `category`. The preference for values in the `category` column are given in this order {'PT','DI','GT','SY'}.

My output dataframe looks like below:

```
  Name Course Cateory
1: Jason     ML      PT
2: Jason     DS      DI
3: Nancy     ML      PT
4: Nancy     DS      DI
5: James     ML      SY
6:  John     DS      GT
```

Currently, I am using a combination of `for` loop and `if` condition. Since the Input dataframe is massive (10 Million rows), it takes forever. Is there a better and efficient way to perform the same?

Comment: Seems like you are removing based on the columns `Name` and `Course`. Check again.

Comment: In a way you are right. But still the deletion depends on the `category` column and in specific order.

Comment: The question does not make that clear. Order by the `Category` column first and then remove duplicates based on `Name` and `Course`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a snippet that does what you asked:

```
df$Category <- factor(df$Category, levels = c("PT", "DI", "GT", "SY"))

df <- df[order(df$Category),]

df[!duplicated(df[,c('Name', 'Course')]),]
```

Output:

```
Name Course Category
Jason     ML       PT
Nancy     ML       PT
Jason     DS       DI
Nancy     DS       DI
John      DS       GT
James     ML       SY
```

Idea is that we sort based on the priority structure. Then we apply the unique operations, which will return the first match. The return will be what we want.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned you have 10 million rows, here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(factor(Category, levels = c("PT","DI","GT","SY")))], by=.(Name, Course)]
```

**Result:**

```
    Name Course Category
1: Jason     ML       PT
2: Jason     DS       DI
3: Nancy     ML       PT
4: Nancy     DS       DI
5: James     ML       SY
6:  John     DS       GT
```

**Benchmarking:**

```
# Random resampling of `df` to generate 10 million rows
set.seed(123)
df_large = data.frame(lapply(df, sample, 1e7, replace = TRUE))

# Data prep Base R  
df1 <- df_large

df1$Category <- factor(df1$Category, levels = c("PT", "DI", "GT", "SY"))

df1 <- df1[order(df1$Category), ]

# Data prep data.table
df2 <- df_large

df2$Category <- factor(df2$Category, levels = c("PT", "DI", "GT", "SY"))

setDT(df2)
```

Results:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(df1[!duplicated(df1[,c('Name', 'Course')]), ], 
               df2[, .SD[which.min(df2$Category)], by=.(Name, Course)])

Unit: milliseconds
                                                      expr       min        lq      mean
            df1[!duplicated(df1[, c("Name", "Course")]), ] 1696.7585 1719.4932 1788.5821
 df2[, .SD[which.min(df2$Category)], by = .(Name, Course)]  387.8435  409.9365  436.4381
    median        uq       max neval
 1774.3131 1803.7565 2085.9722   100
  427.6739  451.1776  558.2749   100
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("James", "Jason", "John", "Nancy"
), class = "factor"), Course = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("DS", "ML"), class = "factor"), 
    Category = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("DI", "GT", "PT", "SY"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Course", "Category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:", "7:", "8:", "9:", "10:", "11:", 
"12:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not removing based on `category`, you're really trying to remove full duplicate rows from the dataframe.

You can remove full duplicate rows by subsetting the dataframe:

```
base R:
df_without_dupes <- df[!duplicated(df),]
```

Comment: I usually use `unique` to remove duplicates but how does your solution answer my question?

Comment: it subsets your original dataframe to remove duplicates, unique would work. I was just about to add in the factor sorting but Cihan already added it in.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `dplyr` package for this

See below:

```
require(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(
    Category_factored=as.numeric(factor(Category,levels=c('PT','DI','GT','SY'),labels=1:4))
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Name,Course) %>% 
  filter(
    Category_factored == min(Category_factored)
  )
```

In case you are new to R, install dplyr using `install.packages('dplyr')`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an index to represent the order of category. Then sort based on the priority of your categories and dedup by Name and Course.

```
library(tidyverse)

#create index to sort by
index.df <- data.frame("Cateory" = c('PT',"DI","GT","SY"), "Index" = c(1,2,3,4))

#join to orig dataset
data <- left_join(data, index.df, by = "Cateory")

#sort by index, dedup with Name and Course
data %>% arrange(Index) %>% group_by(Name,Course) %>% 
distinct(Name,Course, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% select(-Index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick benchmark for given solutions:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# 1. Data set
df_raw <- data.frame(
  name = c("Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Nancy", "Nancy", "Nancy", "Nancy", "James", "John"),
  course = c("ML", "ML", "ML", "ML", "DS", "DS", "ML", "ML", "DS", "DS", "ML", "DS"),
  category = c("PT", "DI", "GT", "SY", "SY", "DI", "PT", "SY", "DI", "GT", "SY", "GT"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 # 3. Solution 'basic R'
 f1 <- function(){

 # 1. Create data set  
  df <- df_raw

 # 2. Convert 'category' as factor
 df$category <- factor(df$category, levels = c("PT", "DI", "GT", "SY"))

 # 3. Sort by 'category'
 df <- df[order(df$category), ]

 # 4. Select rows without duplicates by 'name' and 'course'
 df[!duplicated(df[,c('name', 'course')]), ]

}

# 4. Solution 'dplyr'
f2 <- function(){
  # 1. Create data set
  df <- df_raw

  # 2. Solution
  df_raw %>% 
    mutate(category_factored = as.numeric(factor(category, levels = c('PT','DI','GT','SY'), labels = 1:4))) %>% 
    group_by(name, course) %>% 
    filter(category_factored == min(category_factored))
}

# 5. Solution 'data.table'
f3 <- function(){
  # 1. Create data set
  df <- df_raw

  # 2. Solution
  setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(factor(category, levels = c("PT","DI","GT","SY")))], by=.(name, course)]
}

# 6. Solution 'dplyr'
f4 <- function(){

  # 1. Create data set
  df <- df_raw

  # 2. Create 'index' to sort by
  df_index <- data.frame("category" = c('PT',"DI","GT","SY"), "index" = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

  # 3. Join to original dataset
  df <- left_join(df, df_index, by = "category")

  # 4. Sort by 'index', dedup with 'name' and 'course'
  df %>% 
    arrange(index) %>% 
    group_by(name, course) %>% 
    distinct(name, course, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    select(-index)
}

# Test for solutions
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4())

Unit: milliseconds
expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
f1()  1.350875  1.468044  1.682641  1.603816  1.687203  5.006231   100 a   
f2() 12.547863 12.864521 13.766343 13.543806 14.227795 18.350335   100   c 
f3()  2.517014  2.634612  2.944483  2.792619  2.873013  9.355626   100  b  
f4() 21.073892 21.608212 23.246332 22.338600 23.934932 41.883938   100    d
```

The best solutions are **f1()** and **f3()** as you can see.

Comment: Note that these benchmarks are based on small datasets. Testing on a dataset with 10 million rows, my `data.table` solution is more than 4 times as fast as the base R solution.

Comment: Wow! So, it's the best solution here as by performance and code style. I definitely like it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late, but i believe this is the simplest solution. Since you mentioned 10m rows i propose a data.table implementation using the very understandable `unique` function

```
require("data.table")
df <- data.table("Name" = c("Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Nancy", "Nancy", "Nancy", "Nancy", "James", "John"), "Course" = c("ML", "ML", "ML", "ML", "DS", "DS", "ML", "ML", "DS", "DS", "ML", "DS"), "category" = c("PT", "DI", "GT", "SY", "SY", "DI", "PT", "SY", "DI", "GT", "SY", "GT"))

unique(df[, category := factor(category, levels = c("PT","DI","GT","SY"))][order(df$"category")], by = c("Name", "Course"))

    Name Course category
1: Jason     ML       PT
2: Nancy     ML       PT
3: Jason     DS       DI
4: Nancy     DS       DI
5:  John     DS       GT
6: James     ML       SY
```