# Get distinct rows from dataframe with specific condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID    Name    Value 
1     John    17
1             17
2             NULL
3             NULL
4    Mike     35
4    Mike     NULL  
5    Leo      22
5    Leo
```

I want there be only rows with unique ID. I need to keep those rows with maximally full columns. So, desired result is:

```
ID    Name    Value 
1     John    17
2             NULL
3             NULL
4    Mike     35
5    Leo      22
```

As you see, all ID are kept, but now there are only hose with maximally full columns. How could i do that?

I tried df[complete_cases(df),] , but it removed fully empty rows (ID 2 and 3)

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Sotos i tried to use distinct() and fill() functions, but it didn't work. I really don't understand how to make that complicated subset

Comment: @Sotos i also tried df[complete_cases(df),] , but it removed fully empty rows (ID 2 and 3)

Comment: distinct(df, ID, .keep_all = TRUE)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: Remove duplicates from a dataframe based on categories in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539860/r-remove-duplicates-from-a-dataframe-based-on-categories-in-a-column)

Comment: Try converting NULLs to NAs, order and then  remove the duplicates. The order will ensure that NA is always 2nd

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dplyr::distinct()` in a pipe like that:

`df %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)`  (.keep_all = TRUE to keep other columns)

or in base R

`df[!duplicated(df$ID),]`

both would do the job

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` with option `na.action=na.pass`.

```
aggregate(cbind(Value, Name) ~ ID, dat, el, na.action=na.pass)
#   ID Value Name
# 1  1    17 John
# 2  2  NULL <NA>
# 3  3  NULL <NA>
# 4  4    35 Mike
# 5  5    22  Leo
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), Name = c("John", 
NA, NA, NA, "Mike", "Mike", "Leo", "Leo"), Value = c("17", "17", 
"NULL", "NULL", "35", NA, "22", "NULL")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```