# Removing duplicates based on a specific category of another column

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicate `IDs` in my data using the `Category` columns. A subset of my data is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,1,4,2),
                 category=c("a","b","c","d","b","a","a"))
df

  ID category
1  1        a
2  2        b
3  3        c
4  4        d
5  1        b
6  4        a
7  2        a
```

If there is a duplicated `ID` from `Category b` , I need to keep it and remove the corresponding ID from other categories. And, I have no priority if the duplicated `IDs` are form other categories excluding `Category b`. So, my favorite outcome is:

```
  ID category
1  2        b
2  3        c
3  4        d
4  1        b
```

I have already read this post : [R: Remove duplicates from a dataframe based on categories in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539860/r-remove-duplicates-from-a-dataframe-based-on-categories-in-a-column/47540016)
but can't find my answer

Comment: @Cihan , would you have any ideas?

Comment: @akrun, thanks! yes, category b is of interest when there is a duplicate ID from two categories one of which is b. Otherwise, no preferences for removing duplicated IDs

Comment: @akrun, thanks! I am running your solution. It worked on the sample data, but real data, it only returns rows corresponding to category b and all other rows are removed.

Comment: Is your logic correct - I understand the logic as get the duplicate ID for category 'b', remove those IDs from other category

Comment: @akrun, perhaps I was not clear. So, I want to remove duplicate IDs and keep a set of distinct set of IDs. But, if there is an ID from from category b and c as an example, I want to keep category b in my data. if an ID is from category a and c for example, I have no preference for keeping either category a or c as long as I keep the ID.

Comment: I got it.  Please check my update.  You don't need any filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do an `arrange` to that 'b' category rows are arranged at the top and then get the `distinct` rows by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     arrange(category != 'b') %>% 
     distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
  ID category
1  2        b
2  1        b
3  3        c
4  4        d
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df[order(df$category != 'b'), ] -> df1
df1[!duplicated(df1$ID), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do:

```
 subset(df, !category %in% category[ID %in% ID[category == 'b'] & category !='b'])
  ID category
1  2        b
2  3        c
3  4        d
4  1        b
```